# A problem about Hololens authorization of accessing data

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uwp, visual-studio-2017, hololens

#### An error about app data access failed

I used **Unity3d(2017.4.1 f1)** to export my app to VS2017,but I found that a .xml document(in the directory /Asset/.xml) wasn't exported.So I copied the xml document to /app/data.Then I debugged again,the error happened,it told me I didn't have a authorization to access the data.So how can I solve this problem?Can I change a directory and which  directory can I read?

Error

```
    Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in System.IO.FileSystem.dll
UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\BeautifulSolarVS.Debug_x86.hp\Data\solar.xml' is denied.
   at System.IO.Win32FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs)
   at System.IO.Win32FileSystem.Open(String fullPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, FileStream parent)
   at System.IO.MultiplexingWin32WinRTFileSystem.Open(String fullPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, FileStream parent)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode)
   at OperationAll.QueryXml(String xmlname, String queryingname)
   at OperationAll.HoloToolkit.Unity.InputModule.IFocusable.OnFocusEnter()
   at HoloToolkit.Unity.InputModule.InputManager.<>c.<.cctor>b__118_0(IFocusable handler, BaseEventData eventData)
   at UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute[T](GameObject target, BaseEventData eventData, EventFunction`1 functor)
```

My code

```
 string QueryXml(string xmlname,string queryingname)
    {
        string filepath = Application.dataPath +@xmlname;
        StreamReader fp = new 
        StreamReader(newFileStream(filepath,FileMode.Open));

    if (File.Exists(filepath))
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(fp);

        XmlNodeList nodelist = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("sample");           
        foreach (XmlElement xe in nodelist)
        {
            if (xe.FirstChild.InnerText == queryingname)
            {
                return xe.LastChild.InnerText;
            }

        }
    }
    return null;
}
void IFocusable.OnFocusEnter()
    {
        this.gameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1.5f, 1.5f,1.5f);
        string ob_selected_name = this.transform.name;
        string ob_attribute = QueryXml(xml_name, ob_selected_name);
        GameObject.Find("Panel1/Display/Text").GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Text().text = ob_attribute;}
```

And I have read [MS document for UWP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions),but I am not sure where my xml and the appdatapath are.
There are my test codes

```
//test1
   string QueryXml(string xmlname,string queryingname)
{
    try
    {

        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

        var asyncOpt = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForReadAsync(xmlname);
        asyncOpt.Wait();
        using (var fileStream = asyncOpt.Result)
        {
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(fileStream, settings))
            {
                //加载Xml文件
                xmlDoc.Load(reader);
            }
            XmlNodeList nodelist = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("sample");           
            foreach (XmlElement xe in nodelist)
            {
                if (xe.FirstChild.InnerText == queryingname)
                {
                    return xe.LastChild.InnerText;
                }

            }
        }
    }
    catch (System.Exception e)
    {
        Debug.Log("still fail");
        Debug.Log(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path);


    }
    return null;

}
Error:

Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.AggregateException' in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll
still fail
C:\Data\Users\96385\AppData\Local\Packages\BeautifulSolar_pzq3xp76mxafg\LocalState

//test2
string QueryXmlTest( string queryingname)
{
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    StorageFolder docLib = KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary;
    var docFile = docLib.OpenStreamForReadAsync("Data\\solar.xml");
    docFile.Wait();
    var fs = docFile.Result;
    using (fs)
    {
        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(fs, settings))
        {
            //加载Xml文件
            //Debug.Log(reader);
            xmlDoc.Load(reader);
        }
        XmlNodeList nodelist = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("sample");
        foreach (XmlElement xe in nodelist)
        {
            if (xe.FirstChild.InnerText == queryingname)
            {
                return xe.LastChild.InnerText;
            }

        }
    }
    return null;
}
Error:Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in Assembly-CSharp.dll
UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
   at Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.get_DocumentsLibrary()
```

I don't know where  my solar.xml is and ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder is `C:\Data\Users\96385\AppData\Local\Packages\BeautifulSolar_pzq3xp76mxafg\LocalState`.The location of solar.xml in VS are /App and /App/data(I copied two) The figure[in /data/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpJM5.png)How can I read my xml?

[in /](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOC0L.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [StreamingAssets](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html) folder (Assets/StreamingAssets - create it if it doesn't exist) to include extra XML files in your build.

Copying files manually after a build could be a bad solution, as it's easy to forget later, and will lead to permissions/manifest issues like you're seeing.

To get hold of the file you put into StreamingAssets from a script, you can use [File.ReadAllBytes](https://www.dotnetperls.com/file-readallbytes) with [Application.streamingAssetsPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-streamingAssetsPath.html).

For example:

```
string fileURI = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "myFile.xml");
byte[] xmlAsBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileURI);
```

Comment: But I do not how to access Streaming Asset folder in UWP，there is no introduction for UWP. I only know I can access the ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder or under the same level directory (tempo...).

Comment: Sorry I can't quite understand your English, but have elaborated on my answer.  I hope that helps! (:

Comment: Thanks，I'm not sure if this method is useful because it seems that files on Hololens can only be read using Windows.Storage，and I will test later. What I said before means, I don't know where the files I packed under Asset is in the UWP program，namely，I can't find files in asset in app's local folder when I release it to Hololens.

Comment: aah OK I understand, thanks (:  In my hololens App I have a file in my project "Assets/StreamingAssets/AnchoredGameplayOrigin" and when I build the solution "AnchoredGameplayOrigin" ends up in "[MyAppName]/Data/StreamingAssets".   I can use the data from that file OK on the hololens  (using the code in the answer above, within a coroutine and with error checking which was omitted for clarify), and also have the benefit that it works on other platforms that I build for, without having to know where that platform stores its application files.

Comment: Aha，Thanks，I think I can solve similar problems later.